# Set environment variables within parent shell using a command within a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, mac, environment-variables

I have a shell script containing a single command

```
sudo my_command | parse_to_exports_cmd
```

when I run this script I get the following on stdout

```
export MY_VAR_A=abcdef123
export MY_VAR_B=qwerty123
```

How would I modify my script to actually set these environment variables within the parent shell?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the output in `eval`. This should not be run lightly because it executes any output in the context of your calling shell. You **must trust the output.**

```
eval $(sudo my_command | parse_to_exports_cmd)
```